# Python Selenium can't find XPath

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath

I need to find the XPath for the Text (Can you find me?):
[image]

Tried it for about 10 minutes but wasn't able to do it.

Comment: Try `//*[text(), "Can you find me?")`

Comment: Do you need to get the text or just the element?

Comment: @vitaliis I need the text (Can you find me?)

Comment: @CodeIt I tried that before but it didnt worked somehow? Do you have another suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have id, use it.

```
driver.find_element_by_id("modal-root-header").text
```

If id is not unique for some reason, use xpath:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h4[@id='modal-root-header']").text
```

If `.text` won't work, try `.get_attribute("value")`, or `.get_attribute("innerText")`

Comment: doesnt work 'driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h4[@id='modal-root-header']").text' doesnt have attribute '.text'

Comment: Add html code to your question then. Also, try another option I added.

Comment: It's possible if you'll post a better representation of html you look at.

Comment: Thanks I was a bit stupid your code works, but I forgot to store it in a variable the code I am using now is element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//h4[@id='modal-root-header']").text and check if elements == "Can you find me?" Thanks and sorry for wasting your time :)